# Setup Apache2 for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache2, reverse-proxy

How can I setup Apache2 to access my Spring REST API hosted on Tomcat 8? Is this okay? It doesn't seem to be working.

I was following this tutorial https://medium.com/@mirela95/apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-with-java-back-end-application-running-on-tomcat-9c8c9210783e

Here is my configuration file. It is stored under **sites-available**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass /springrest http://127.0.0.1:8932/
   ProxyPassReverse /springrest http://127.0.0.1:8932/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your entire config file then you don't have enough.  You **must** have the `ServerName` parameter to have things work correctly.  You'll need to use:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /springrest http://localhost:8932/
    ProxyPassReverse /springrest http://127.0.0.1:8932/
    ProxyTimeout 360
</VirtualHost>
```

This file is normally named something like `www.example.com.conf`.  Once you put it into `sites-available` you'll need to run `sudo a2ensite www.example.com` and then `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.